# Письма с сайта на Wordpress (на VPS, Exim4+Dovecot) уходят в спам или отклоняются

Tags: wordpress, email, exim, vesta, dovecot

На VPS имеется несколько простых сайтов и почтовый сервер на exim4+dovecot. Письма с ящика на любой ящик в сети отправляются без проблем.

Но если отправлять письмо с моего сайта (на wordpress) через форму обратной связи, оно с большой вероятностью попадает в спам, а некоторые сервера его вообще отклоняют.

Уже 2 дня пытаюсь найти информацию по этому вопросу, но как-то безрезультатно. Боты типа ChatGPT всякую ерунду отвечают (возможно, запрос не так формирую).

Ниже лог (/var/log/exim4/mainlog) после отправки письма с формы обратной связи wordpress моего сайта на адрес info@mysite.com, дополнительно стоит пересылка на почту gmail.com (в спаме), yandex.ru (в спаме) и mail.ru (отклоняется):

```
2024-01-31 16:25:47 1rVAb5-000olz-U1 <= admin@my-server U=admin P=local S=1352 id=onfBoAxQskLbqqHy6EtNh8iuzLqXypDT3tJpTcNyO8@mysite.com
2024-01-31 16:25:47 1rVAb5-000olz-U1 => info <info@mysite.com> R=localuser T=local_delivery
2024-01-31 16:25:48 1rVAb5-000olz-U1 => R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [64.233.184.26] TFO X=TLS1.3:ECDHE_X25519__ECDSA_SECP256R1_SHA256__AES_256_GCM:256 CV=yes K C="250 2.0.0 OK v11-20020a5d4a4b000000b0033af5ec8012si2907912wrs.753 - gsmtp"
2024-01-31 16:25:49 1rVAb5-000olz-U1 ** my_mail@mail.ru <info@mysite.com> R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=mxs.mail.ru [217.69.139.150] X=TLS1.3:ECDHE_SECP256R1__RSA_PSS_RSAE_SHA256__AES_256_GCM:256 CV=yes: SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data: 550 non-local sender verification failed
2024-01-31 16:25:50 1rVAb5-000olz-U1 => my_mail@yandex.ru <info@mysite.com> R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=mx.yandex.ru [77.88.21.249] X=TLS1.3:ECDHE_SECP256R1__RSA_PSS_RSAE_SHA256__AES_256_GCM:256 CV=yes C="250 2.0.0 Ok: queued on mail-nwsmtp-mxfront-production-main-21.iva.yp-c.yandex.net 1706725848-kUfPFr0SBW20-oezsrFCy"
2024-01-31 16:25:50 1rVAb8-000omB-2d <= <> R=1rVAb5-000olz-U1 U=Debian-exim P=local S=2847
2024-01-31 16:25:50 1rVAb5-000olz-U1 Completed
2024-01-31 16:25:50 1rVAb8-000omB-2d ** admin@my-server: Unrouteable address
2024-01-31 16:25:50 1rVAb8-000omB-2d Frozen (delivery error message)
```

Я правильно понимаю, что в спам письма летят и отклоняются из-за того, что они отправлены локальным пользователем сервера admin@my-server, а не пользователем info почтового ящика info@mysite.com?

Может кто подскажет, что в конфигурации подправить или какие файлы конфигурации/параметры за это отвечают и что нужно изменить?

PS. На VPS установлена платформа VestaCP (правда, на новую ОС Ubuntu 20.04), все конфиги exim4 по умолчанию с момента установки VestaCP.

PS.PS. SPF, DKIM, DMARC записи для доменов настроены и работают отлично

Comment: С вероятностью 99% ты ошибаешься в корректности настроек записей домена. Кроме того, когда маилру отбивает почту, приходит рекветс на мыло постмастера. Там всё написано, читай его.

Comment: Возможно твой сайт хоститься на дишманском хостинге рядом с какой-то гемблинго/порнушной шляпой и тебя цепляет их IP автоматом.... Попробуй поставить на чистую WP отправщик писем, или же наоборот - разверни сайт на другох хостинге.

Comment: @SeVlad, почему тогда напрямую с клиента нормально отправляются письма с info@mysite.com на все эти почтовые ящики, и ни один из этих сервисов их даже в спам не бросает?

Comment: @BlackStar1991, что значит цепляет их ip автоматом? Каким образом? VPS со своей выделеной статикой

Comment: @Maks потому что твой клиент отправляет через правильно настроенный МТА, а не твой сервер. Но ещё остаётся шанс, что IP твоего сервера находится в беклистах.

Comment: @SeVlad, а передачей письмо с сайта на электронную почту МТА не занимается?

Comment: @Maks учи уже матчасть, думай над сказанным выше, а не задавай такие вопросы (задавай правильные). МТА на твоём сервере и МТА, через которого  клиент отправляет - разные серверы,

Comment: @SeVlad, матчасть мне особо здесь не нужна, это единичная задача, которую нужно решить и забыть. Работать в дальнейшем мне с этим не нужно

Comment: @SeVlad, опять же, что не так спросил? пересылкой почты полученной с сайта на адрес электронной почты занимается тоже MTA, конкретно мой MTA Exim4. Пересылкой почты с почтового клиента с адресом отправителя моего сервера тоже проходит через MTA Exim4 моего сервера (это так же демонстрируют логи Exim4). Ты пишешь: "потому что твой клиент отправляет через правильно настроенный МТА". Я отвечаю: "а передачей письма с сайта на электронную почту МТА не занимается?". А ведь как раз-таки этот же мой серверный MTA этим и занимается. Кому надо подучить матчасть??

Comment: @SeVlad. Так вот, какого.. мой "правильно настроенный МТА", не пересылает письма с сайта на адрес электронной почты того же mail.ru? Но без проблем пересылает на тот же адрес напрямую, с почтового клиента? И еще, с плохо настроенными записями домен у меня письма через клиент тоже не отправлял, сейчас без проблем и ошибок. Включая логику, делаем заключение, что записи домена настроены правильно.

Comment: Следуя описанию ошибки в логах "550 non-local sender verification failed", которая почему-то игнорируется, информация следующая: Если адрес отправителя не является локальным для сервера, то сервер может отвергнуть попытку отправки электронной почты. В моем случае, я предполагаю, что письмо в перенаправлении на ящик mail.ru отправляется от имени admin@my-server вместо info@mysite.com. И ниже в логах ответ с ошибкой, видимо, приходит почему-то на эту же почту (admin@my-server) Почему она, откуда она взялась, я пока не могу понять, видно это учетка VestaCP.

Comment: @Maks тескта много, толку мало. Последний раз - это **ты думаешь** что у тебя всё правильно настроено, но что есть по факту отсюда не видно. А ты даже домен зашифровал. На наводящие замечания не реагируешь (видимо не понимаешь о чем речь).  Так что помочь тебе больше не чем. Ну разве что посоветовать костыль - использовать сторонний SMTP (того же яндекса напр).

Comment: Ах да, мыло, отправляемое с сервера должно быть в домене сайта.

Comment: @SeVlad, "На наводящие замечания не реагируешь (видимо не понимаешь о чем речь)" - на какие, например?

Comment: @SeVlad, "Ах да, мыло, отправляемое с сервера должно быть в домене сайта", я на это ещё в тексте вопроса указал, и посчитал это как раз моей проблемой, опять же исходя из лога